# Class of differentiated Gamma functions: are there any algebras where they are elementary?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, special-functions, zeta-functions, gamma-function, poly-gamma-function

There is a class of [differentiated gamma functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/introductions/DifferentiatedGammas/ShowAll.html) (DGFs) that basically can be expressed via derivatives of Gamma function.
They include the Gamma function, Polygamma function, and Hurwitz Zeta function further generalizes the class to fractional orders.

The thing about this class of functions is that they behave like "nearly-elementary".
These are the arguments for this point:

1. DGFs generalize the Bernoulli polynomials to negative orders, particularly, $\psi^{(1)}(x)=B_{-1}(x)$ if we define Bernoulli polynomials via Hurwitz Zeta. With power functions it is the reciprocal functions that generalize them to negative orders, and considered elementary.
2. The antiderivative of the reciprocal function $\frac1x$ is logarithm, an elementary function. The antidifference of the same function is polygamma $\psi(x)$, a DGF.
3. $\psi(x)-\psi(-x)$ is elementary, while $\psi(x)+\psi(-x)$ is a DGF. The Taylor series for these functions differ only in parity. Also, $\frac1{\pi}\psi(1-\frac x\pi)-\frac1{\pi}\psi(\frac x\pi)=\cot x$.
4. Due to Gauss's digamma theorem, the digamma function of a rational argument may be expressed in terms of Euler's constant and a finite number of elementary functions:$$\psi\left(\frac{r}{m}\right) = -\gamma -\ln(2m) -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right) +2\sum_{n=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{m-1}{2} \right\rfloor} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi nr}{m} \right) \ln\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{m}\right)$$

Given the above considerations, the DGFs look like "all-but-elementary" or "nearly elementary" to me. As such, I wonder whether in alternative algebras or extension of real numbers this class of functions can turn out to be truly elementary (expressable via logarithms or trigonometric functions). Does it nicely generalize the class of elementary functions?